# How to code a general Gauss-seidel method

Tags: matlab, methods, gaussian

How can I program a Matlab code for Gauss-Seidel method that able the users to input any number of equations, n and any input for the matrix coefficient?
I did this, but this is for a fix number of equations and known equation's coefficients.
I need a code that where both number of equations, n and the value of coefficients (a11, a12, ..) are given by user.

```
 clear;clc;format('long','g');
 i=1;
 x2(i)=32; x3(i)=41; x4(i)=12;
 error_x1(i)=100;

 while error_x1(i) >= 0.01
 x1(i+1)=(21-x2(i)+42*x3(i)-9*x4(i))/-2;
 x2(i+1)=(-3-4*x1(i)-x3(i)+x4(i))/-12;
 x3(i+1)=(-24-2*x1(i)-6*x2(i)-18*x4(i))/-2;
 x4(i+1)=(41-21*x1(i)+2*x2(i)-x3(i))/-1;

 error_x1(i+1)=abs((x1(i+1)-x1(i))/x1(i+1))*100;
 error_x2(i+1)=abs((x2(i+1)-x2(i))/x2(i+1))*100;
 error_x3(i+1)=abs((x3(i+1)-x3(i))/x3(i+1))*100;
 error_x4(i+1)=abs((x4(i+1)-x4(i))/x4(i+1))*100;

 i=i+1;
 end
 disp('                  x1                    error(%)');
 disp([x1',error_x1'])
 disp('                  x2                    error(%)');
 disp([x2',error_x2'])
 disp('                  x3                    error(%)');
 disp([x3',error_x3'])
 disp('                  x4                    error(%)');
 disp([x4',error_x4'
```

please... help

@DougLipinski, thanks for your help and suggestions. From the code above, it's been changed to the code below.
Basically it's like this.

```
while (n<maxit) && (max(err)>tol)
n = n + 1;%no. of iteration
for i = 1:n_eq
    x(i) = (b(i) - (A(i,:) * x)) / A(i,i) + x(i);%Gauss-Seidel method

    x_old = x;%roots
end
    err = abs((x - x_old) ./ x);%checking for error
end
```

to ask input from user, use the input command
example:

```
 A = input('Give matrix A');
```

and so on.
Good luck.
Credit: Matteo Carpentieri (Uni of Surrey)

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- By always using the results at step `i` to compute step `i+1` (even though `x1(i+1)` is available when computing `x2(i+1)` etc.) you've implemented the Jacobi method, not Gauss-Seidel. They are very similar, but Gauss-Seidel converges about twice as fast and requires less memory.
- There's no reason to store all your intermediate results and errors unless you really want to (i.e., use `x1=...` instead of `x1(i+1)=...`
- MATLAB stands for *MATrix LABoratory*, learn to use arrays, matrices, and vectors when possible. This is the key aspect of your question. Instead of having different variables for `x1`, `x2`, ..., store them all in a single variable called `x`. Likewise, store all your matrix coefficients in a matrix `A`. A single Gauss-Seidel iteration can then be coded as:
  `for i=1:length(x)
      I=[1:i-1 i+1:length(x)];
      x(i) = ( b(i)-A(i,I)*x(I) )/A(i,i);
  end`
  where `A` is your matrix and `b` is the right hand side. If you're not comfortable with matrix and vector operations consider reviewing some linear algebra and MATLAB focused linear algebra tutorials.
- Checking the error based on only a single component of your solution is not a good idea in general. You should really use an error norm such as `norm(xnew-xold)/norm(xnew)`.

I hope this helps, but based on your code it seems like you're having trouble conceptualizing the algorithm and translating the necessary steps into code. The first step is to really understand what you want to do on a step by step basis and the second is to code that as a functioning program.